# Getting proper return from Wordpress Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, blogs

y'all.

So I'm trying to get our Wordpress blog to show on a distinct page in our HTML-based website.  I've done a lot of research and I have a pretty good idea how I'm supposed to proceed (I think), but I don't think I'm pulling the correct Loop code to do it.

The page is here: www.cidermag.com/blog.php

As you can see, the site returns a value of "Nothing Found" even though we have about three or four test posts already published through the WP Dashboard.  HOWEVER, the fact that I got that part of the Loop to return gives me hope that I'm on the right track....

Per instructions that I found online, I pulled the Loop code from the index.php file located in our /blog/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve folder.  I know I will have to program specific values for specific things but I just need to at least get the blog showing right now so I have a starting point for understanding this beast.  (I learn better by doing than by reading.)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I can't seem to find a definitive answer on this.  Thank you!

The Loop php Code:

```
<?php require('blog/wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">

        <?php if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) :
            // Show a different message to a logged-in user who can add posts.
        ?>
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'No posts to display', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <p><?php printf( __( 'Ready to publish your first post? <a href="%s">Get started here</a>.', 'twentytwelve' ), admin_url( 'post-new.php' ) ); ?></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        <?php else :
            // Show the default message to everyone else.
        ?>
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        <?php endif; // end current_user_can() check ?>

        </article><!-- #post-0 -->

    <?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>
```

Comment: Please post some of the relevent php code in order to help you with your question

Comment: What is your blog's URL?  http://cidermag.com/blog/? I see posts there.  Have you set the theme?  Why does the URL you gave us end in .php?

Comment: /blog is the location where we installed WP (per instructions).  But, as this is not a WP site, everything we read said we needed to rename the HTML page with a .php extension.  Hence the page URL.  We have not set any theme as the ultimate goal is for visitors to never see the WP default page - only the posts on our HTML site.

Answer (score 0):

This whole thing seems like a really bad idea. I would strongly recommend that you do things the right way: create a theme, and maybe put your whole site into WordPress.

If that is out of the question, you should be able to get it to work by creating a custom query:

```
<?php
    $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1 // this will display all available posts

    ) );
?>

<?php if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>

// your loop code

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

// your code for when no posts exists

<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: why "a bad idea"?  There are sites all over the web that do exactly what we're trying to do - integrate php calls into html sites.  The difference is, we just don't know how to do it.  I absolutely appreciate the help, by the way - just trying to get some context to your thoughts....WP actually gives the instructions on how to do this action (ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website ), but the Loop code in my theme only calls the "Nothing Found" action.  So I guess my root question should be: Where do I find the proper, complete, Loop code for our theme?

Comment: You find it in my answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help - we're not interested in being slaved to WP for our entire site so we'll find a solution.  Thank you again!

Comment: I provided a wordpress loop that should work. Give it a shot.

Comment: You can also use simple php includes to bring in the header, footer, etc from your existing site while still using wordpress in a sensible way.